# Can't set UINavigationController title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

So here's how I set up things in my app. I have a `UINavigationController` which has a `UITabBarController` as the `rootViewController`. The `rootViewController` has 3 tabs in it. I have tried many different ways to set the title, ranging from:

`self.title = @"title";`

`self.navigationController.title = @"title";`

`self.navigationItem.title = @"title";`

and none of it works

Why is this?

**UPDATE:**

for some weird reason  `self.parentViewController.title = @"Map";` actually worked....

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644555/uitabbaritem-title-vs-uinavigationcontroller-title solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want is to set the text that appears in the center of the navigation bar. If so, `navigationItem` is definitely not what you want. That's for setting buttons in the navigation bar.

The less obvious part of setting the title is that the text that will appear in the navigation bar is the title of the `ViewController` that is on top. In other words, the last `ViewController` that was pushed. So what you want to do is to set your `self.title` in your `ViewContoller`. You can do it `ViewContoller`'s `init` or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: For this to work, be sure your ViewController is connected in Interface Builder's Identity Inspector via the Custom Class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I tried NSLogging every title attribute from the navigation bar, eventually for me it worked to set the navBar.topItem.title attribute. Of course, navBar is a reference to the UINavigationBar in my IB.

Answer (score 0):

`self.title` should be what you use.

1.) When are you trying to change the title? for example, when pressing a tab button?

2.) Where are you placing this code? This should be in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: yes I did put it in viewDidLoad as self.title = @"Map";, it doesn't work. I am trying to show a title when the view initially shows up.. otherwise there's no title, as of now it just shows Root View Controller as the title

Comment: `self.title` should be set in `init` since it could be used before the view is loaded. Like in a tab bar, the title of the tab is used even if the view is loaded only when you change tab.

Comment: and yes I am using initWithTabBar, I did try self.title there, no effect

Comment: `initWithTabBar` is your issue then, use `.parentViewController.title`.

Comment: why is initWithTabBar is an issue?

Answer (score -1):

Here it comes....

You must write following line to add tabbarcontroller in appdelegate..

```
mTabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];


    TSDetailTaskController *mTSDetailTaskController = [[TSDetailTaskController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSDetailTaskController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mTaskNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSDetailTaskController];
    mTaskNavBar.tabBarItem.title=@"Task List";
    mTaskNavBar.tabBarItem.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_114_list.png"];
    [mTSDetailTaskController release];

    mTSSearchController=[[TSSearchController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSSearchController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mSearchNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSSearchController];
    mSearchNavBar.title=@"Search";
    mSearchNavBar.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_009_search.png"];
    [mTSSearchController release];

    TSSettingController *mTSSettingController = [[TSSettingController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TSSettingController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *mSettingNavBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mTSSettingController];
    mSettingNavBar.tabBarItem.title=@"Setting";
    mSettingNavBar.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_280_settings.png"];
    [mTSSettingController release];


    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mTaskNavBar];  
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mSearchNavBar];
    [localViewControllersArray addObject:mSettingNavBar];

    [mTaskNavBar release];
    [mSearchNavBar release];
    [mSettingNavBar release];


    mTabBar.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    mTabBar.view.autoresizingMask==(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    [localViewControllersArray release];


    [window addSubview:mTabBar.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

I suppose that u r creating ur project based on UINavigation controller type...

then in the  "ViewDidLoad" of ur rootviewcontroller 
try `self.title`

Hope this eill help u out..

Comment: why do I have to add another UINavigationController again on top of it? doing that gives me this http://imgur.com/kPQg5